# What is the correct pronunciation of 辫发？

Tags: pronunciation, word, pinyin

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=zh-CN&tl=en&text=%E8%BE%AB%E5%8F%91) and [查查在线词典](http://www.ichacha.net/%E8%BE%AB%E5%8F%91.html) both say 辫发 ought to be biànfǎ, but [Baidu](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%BE%AB%E5%8F%91) says biànfā. What is correct?

Comment: Interestingly, the sound file for iChaCha 查查在线词典 sounds like it corresponds to another variant: biànfà

Comment: oh good catch, I didn't even listen to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on region.

This word 辮髮 is quite transparent: 辮 braid + 髮 hair (of the head).

Hence, in standard Taiwan Mandarin, as defined by Ministry of Education there, both characters have a single pronunciation each, and so [the word as a whole](https://www.moedict.tw/%E8%BE%AE%E9%AB%AE) is pronounced *biànfǎ*.

On the mainland though, the second one 髮 was defined as being pronounced as fà on its own. This is where 辮髮 is pronounced *biànfà*; however, I do not see *authoritative sources* which say this is prescriptively correct, despite it being a common way of pronouncing this on the Mainland.

The character 髮 was merged with 發 fā and underwent character simplification to form 发. As 發/发 fā has become more common, this is where 辮髮 = 辫发 gained its third pronunciation, *biànfā*, which is the [pronunciation on zDic.net](http://www.zdic.net/hans/%E8%BE%AB%E5%8F%91).

Comment: I'm pretty sure fā is incorrect and is a computer mistake. Xinhua is almost as precriptive as it gets but I should check Modern Chinese Dictionary to be sure (unfortunately not by my hand though).

Answer (score 2):

According to Xinhua Zidian, the only admitted standard pronunciation currently for 发 (in Mainland) is

- fā, various meanings, e.g. "to send out, to dispatch", "to start", "to grow, to expand", "to open, to reveal, to invent", "to show", "to produce, to happen"; and
- fà, meaning "hair".

As 发 in 辫发 refers to hair, it should be pronounced biànfà in Mainland China. This is also how I pronounce the word (native speaker).

In Taiwan, as indicated by the other answer, fǎ is correct.